# Making Api Calls using Inheritance as a wrapper

Tags: c#, api, inheritance

I am trying to build an application that handles making lots of API requests to 2 or 3 related APIs.  My general strategy is to have one base class `ApiRequest` that has:

```
List<Parameter> Parameters
Uri CombinedUri
string Results
string _Host
```

and methods:

```
CombineUri() //combines the _Host and parameters into full Uri
MakeRequest() //makes the request and stores Results
```

Then I would inherit that base class into many different Api Calls and implement functions in those specific to that Api call.

The problem I have is that I call `CombineUri()` in my base classes constructor, but it requires that `_Host` already be set.  However, I want `_Host` to be a constant in each child class since it is specific for each different Api call.  I do not want to have to remember to call `CombineUri` from every derived class' constructor.

Any ideas to get around that problem would be greatly appreciated.  Also, if you have a different design idea entirely for implementing a base for Api calls I would be all ears.  I am not sure my approach is the best.

Thanks.

**My Solution:**

I implemented ideas from both John and Colin Pear.
I changed the base `ApiRequest` into an abstract class, and I moved the `CombineUri()` method into the `MakeRequest()` method.

I also went further and changed `ApiRequest` into a generic class and changed `_Host` into a `static string`.  This way, each subclass with subclass `ApiRequest<*subclassname*>`.  Due to the properties of generics, each object of a particular subclass will share a static `_Host`.

Comment: Just pass the specific host you want to the superclass constructor.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that as I am deriving from the base class for each separate Api call and felt it would be weird to have these constant Api host strings laying around in my other code.  Thoughts?

Comment: I think you may be wanting an abstract base class.

Comment: @ColinPear I think you might be right.  However, how would I implement a static host string in the abstract definition that must be in the subclasses.  Would an abstract property with no setter be the best approach?

Comment: Whats the purpose of making it static? Your base class variables and methods will be available to all of your classes that inherit from it. If you want to make it read only you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making CombineUri() private and then call it inside the implementation of MakeRequest().

The user of this class should not have to know that they need to call two methods, and furthermore, that they have to call CombineUri before they call MakeRequest. That's an implementation detail that belongs inside MakeRequest.

It's possible I don't fully understand the classes, but if I do, then I would make CombineUri private and always call it as the first part of MakeRequest.

Comment: So simple and makes more sense there as the parameters could change during the life of a request requiring a rebuilding of the uri.  Thanks.  Do you have a suggestion for how to make the `_Host` string a static in the subclasses?

Comment: If the base takes host in it's constructor, and you make the base constructor internal, only derived types will be able to create a base.